# Python: Pandas - tidy data frame from multiple header excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, import

I have an excel sheet output from a software tool that is structured in the following multi-header way.
excel structure:

```
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       |              |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       | not relevant | not relevant |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       | X1           | Y1           |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|fr | Time  | not relevant | not relevant |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 1 | 0.000 | 12           | 32           |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 2 | 0.010 | 23           | 3            |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 3 | 0.020 | 45           | 4            |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 4 | 0.030 | 4            | 1            |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       |              |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       | not relevant |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       | Y2           |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|fr | Time  | not relevant |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 1 | 0.000 | 5            |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 2 | 0.010 | 89           |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 3 | 0.020 | 5            |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 4 | 0.030 | 3            |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       |              |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       | not relevant |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   |       | X3           |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
|fr | Time  | not relevant |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 1 | 0.000 | 17           |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 2 | 0.010 | 2            |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 3 | 0.020 | 4            |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 4 | 0.030 | 23           |              |
+---+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

csv structure:

```
,,,
,,not relevant,not relevant
,,X1,Y1
fr,Time,not relevant,not relevant
1,0.000,12,32
2,0.010,23,3
3,0.020,45,4
4,0.030,4,1
,,,
,,not relevant,
,,Y2,
fr,Time,not relevant,
1,0.000,5,
2,0.010,89,
3,0.020,5,
4,0.030,3,
,,,
,,not relevant,
,,X3,
fr,Time,not relevant,
1,0.000,17,
2,0.010,2,
3,0.020,4,
4,0.030,23,
```

I am looking for a fast way to convert this messy data into a tidy pandas dataframe.

- The timestamps are identical in value and number for each individual sub-series.
- the number of sub-series is variable.

The end result should look as follows.

```
  Time    X1     Y1     Y2     X3  
  0.000   12     32     5      17    
  0.010   23     3      89     2     
  0.020   45     4      5      4     
  0.030   4      1      3      23
```

Comment: Lookup `skiprows` parameter in `pd.read_excel` method. You would be able to get your desired output easily.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I am aware of  `skiprows` , easy to use for skipping rows at the top but the challenge here is that multiple sub series are concatenated in the excel data.
I might just do it the old fashion way using `.split`

Answer (score 0):

I did the following... not super happy about it, but it works.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename = 'test_data'

df = pd.read_excel(filename + '.xlsx', header=None)

df_list = np.split(df, df[df.isnull().all(1)].index)

del df_list[0]

for i, df in enumerate(df_list):

    df.iloc[3, 2:] = df.iloc[2, 2:]

    new_header = df.iloc[3]
    df.columns = new_header

    df = df.iloc[4:]
    df_tmp = df.drop(['Frame'], axis=1)    
    df = df_tmp.set_index("Time")
    df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)    
    df.columns.name = None

    df_list[i] = df

df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)

df.to_csv(filename + '.csv')
```